# fabric.js rotate a combined path

Tags: javascript, charts, rotation

I already searched for days and tried really a lot of things to get this right.

I want to use piecharts as progress pie. I created two fabric paths, which draws the pie chart and it works as it should.
Now I want to rotate the paths at the center point, but it doesn't work. It's actually a simple rotation. The main problem is, that the rotation point depends on the ratio of the chart. I have multiple charts and if I change one, all other charts changes as well.

I combined the two paths into a group, so every piechart is a group containing two paths.

Here are two of my piecharts. Selectable true to see what is selected.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Uv1.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfTnq.png

I want the selectable Rectangle to be evenly spaced out over the whole circle, so that the rotation point is exactly at the center. I don't understand why the selectable area is always the smaller part of the pie chart.

Can anybody help me out?

That's how I calculate the pie chart

```
for(var i = 0; i < sectorAngleArr.length; i++)
{
    startAngle = endAngle;  
    endAngle = startAngle + sectorAngleArr[i];

    x1 = parseInt(left - (mainProgRad) * Math.sin(Math.PI*startAngle / 180)); 
    y1 = parseInt(top - (mainProgRad) * Math.cos(Math.PI*startAngle / 180)); 

    x2 = parseInt(left - (mainProgRad) * Math.sin(Math.PI * endAngle / 180));
    y2 = parseInt(top - (mainProgRad)  * Math.cos(Math.PI * endAngle / 180));
```

And thats how I draw it

```
if(i == 0 && sectorAngleArr[0] <= 180)
    {
        pathString = "M " +  (left) + "," + (top) + " L " + (x1) + "," + (y1) + " A " + mainProgRad + "," + mainProgRad + " 0 0,0 " + (x2) + "," + (y2) + " z";     
        var path0 = new fabric.Path(pathString);

        path0.set(
        {
            fill:" rgba(80, 80, 220, 0.4)",
            stroke:"#0000cc",
            strokeWidth:"1",

        });
    }
    else if(i == 0 && sectorAngleArr[0] > 180)
    {   
        pathString = "M " +  (left) + "," + (top) + " L " + (x1) + "," + (y1) + " A " + mainProgRad + "," + mainProgRad + " 0 1,0 " + (x2) + "," + (y2) + " z";
        var path0 = new fabric.Path(pathString);

        path0.set(
        {
            fill:" rgba(80, 80, 220, 0.4)",
            stroke:"#0000cc",
            strokeWidth:"1",

            });

    }
    else if(i == 1 && sectorAngleArr[1] <= 180)
    {
        pathString = "M " +  (left) + "," + (top) + " L " + (x1) + "," + (y1) + " A " + mainProgRad + "," + mainProgRad + " 0 0,0 " + (x2) + "," + (y2) + " z";
        var path1 = new fabric.Path(pathString);

        path1.set(
        {

            fill:" rgba(220, 80, 80, 0.4)",
            stroke:"#cc00cc",
            strokeWidth:"1",
        });
    }
    else
    {
        pathString = "M " +  (left) + "," + (top) + " L " + (x1) + "," + (y1) + " A " + mainProgRad + "," + mainProgRad + " 0 1,0 " + (x2) + "," + (y2) + " z";
        var path1 = new fabric.Path(pathString);

        path1.set(
        {
            fill:" rgba(220, 80, 80, 0.4)",
            stroke:"#cc00cc",
            strokeWidth:"1",
        });
    }
}   

var progressGroup = new fabric.Group([path0, path1],
        {
            left: left,
            top: top,
            originX: "center",
            originY: "center",
            scaleX: -1,
            selectable:true
        });
        all.add(progressGroup);
```

I hope you can help me out!

EDIT: One good step forward was to use fabric.Pathgroup instead of fabric.Group...it reacts more as expected. But its still not working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I find a workaround. The problem was, that the arc was ignored and the selecable area was around the 2 lines which were drawn. So I created more pieces of the pie to get the selectable area surrounding the wohle pie chart and the center, was now the center

You can see it here

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKEzP.png

EDIT: After getting some problems with an odd amount of pieces I made it just easy and drew a rectangle behind the pie chart and made it invisible. It is necessary that the rectangle has an absolute position. Now everthing works fine! :)